# Is there a difference between filters and categories in Django

Tags: python, django, filter, categories

I am building my first eCommerce Python `django` site. I already have filters in place:

In short, when you sort something you are putting it into a `category`. So my question is:

> How do I set about creating product categories? Is this just another
>   word for filter.
>
> I want to be a separate header for each `product categories`. Should I
>   have a different app for each `product`?

Comment: 1. If you want to sort, you sort. If you want combine you create categories. The rest of the question is unclear.
2. Unclear what you mean by different app, but for sure you can create category with customizable header and page.

Comment: By `filter` do you mean *"filter by price, size, colour etc."* as seen on e-commerce websites? If you want this ability, these fields should be present on your product model. BTW, personally I'd advise you to use existing solutions for a generic site like e-commerce instead of coding your own. It's not worth it to spend your whole month coding something which you can set up in 10 minutes pretty much for free.

Comment: filters: would determine things like price, saloon, cabrio, family, cc but is a category just another filter